# Implementing spatial tables in a database

Tags: spatial-database, ogc

Is there a OGC specification on how to implement spatial data storage in a database?

I was looking at the tinydb for spatial data storage, but I was wondering what is a standard way to store spatial data.

Comment: As iant has pointed out, there is an OGC standard which defines storage and SQL functionality. This is implemented by several database implementations, each with their own strengths/weaknesses.

Comment: The OGC standard details how the SQL language is to be altered, but there are no standards on how to *deploy* spatial database tables within the SQL engine.

Comment: Agreed there are pluses and minuses to each.  I am disappointed by the py spatialite package for its lack of support, and I don't want to install gdal libraries, because it is too big of a package.  I like the idea of tinydb because it's pure Python and no secondary installations like geoslib etc..

Answer (score 1):

You need the [OGC Simple Feature Specification - SQL Option](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfs).

> This second part of OpenGIS® Simple Features Access (SFA), also called ISO 19125, is to define a standard
>   Structured Query Language (SQL) schema that supports storage, retrieval, query and update of feature
>   collections via the SQL Call-Level Interface (SQL/CLI) (ISO/IEC 9075-3:2003). A feature has both spatial and non-
>   spatial attributes. Spatial attributes are geometry valued, and simple features are based on two-or-fewer
>   dimensional geometric (point, curve and surface) entities in 2 or 3 spatial dimensions with linear or planar
>   interpolation between vertices. This standard is dependent on the common architectural components defined in
>   Part 1 of this standard.